# Helm-Projectile find -perm /444 illegal mode string

Tags: helm, mode-line, projectile

I'm using emacs on the mac and helm-projectile is acting up.

[image]

It's still working for files in current dired buffer, but the find-files feature is throwing the error:

```
find: -perm /444: illegal mode string
```

I recently installed [powerline](https://github.com/jonathanchu/emacs-powerline) and I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the mode line, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Has anyone ever had this error before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `-perm /444` is specific to the GNU `find` command, so it works on Linux but not on other Unix systems such as OSX. It looks for files that are readable by at least one user, which is pretty useless in practice since it's quite rare for a file not to be readable by anyone. `-readable` (which matches files that are readable to you) would be useful, but it too is a GNU extension which is not available on OSX. If you find what's issuing it, just remove the `-perm /444` bit altogether.

There's no `-perm /444` in Helm or Projectile from Git. However there was a use of `-perm /444` in Projectile for a few weeks in July 2015, in an attempt to fix [issue #695](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/695). This is probably what you're seeing. It was [introduced on 2015-07-28](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/commit/aa1a44d7b9f71e3612da699d2ac4c89c16ebb3e6) and [fixed on 2015-08-07](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/commit/926d6f7fafc8acab16b04de0b5b7b19f6062bfed), so just upgrading helm-projectile to the latest version on MELPA (currently 20150826.321) should work.

Comment: Thanks I had transferred my emacs config from Ubuntu, and that's why it worked before.